# Is there a way to prevent Xcode from modifying the inode number of my source file?

Tags: macos, xcode

I've made a hardlink of my source file. But when I edit the source file and `⌘s` it, the inode number of it changed and the hardlink was broken. How to protect my hardlinks from being broken?

Comment: A quick tip: You almost always want to be using symlinks and not hardlinks. Even aside from this particular issue (already explained well in the answers), symlinks are generally easier to work with, and there are very few cases where you truly need properties that are specific to hard links.

Answer (score 9):

Hardlinks break if the editor used writes a new file each time you save (instead of just overwriting the existing ones). There are pros and cons to both approaches, but relevant here is that it is decided by the implementation of the editor in question (Xcode in your case) and can't be easily changed.

Depending on what you want to accomplish you could use symbolic links instead.

Comment: I tried. Symbolinks works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Xcode *always* writes to a new file, then when the new file is written it renames the old file, renames the new file, then unlinks the old file. That way, if your computer loses power at any point during saving, all your files are intact. The "other" hard link will be unmodified and point to the file whose inode was just unlinked by Xcode. Nothing you can do about that.

Symbolic links work differently.